# MAUI CollectionView Span Property Bug

Tags: collectionview, maui

MAUI, VS17.4 pr1, Windows.
I Set CollectionView Span value to 3, So if I have only 1 or 2 objects, the CollectionView will display nothing.
I attached a runable project on my Synology.

[BugProject](http://darksnow.cn:8885/sharing/0l5mAmaLZ)

BTW, ScrollBar doesn't show in the View.

Whole XAML Page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiApp1.VerticalListDynamicSizeItemsPage"
         Title="Vertical list (dynamic item sizing)">
<StackLayout>
    <Button TextColor="Wheat"
            Text="Add New "
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    <Button TextColor="Wheat"
            Text="Delete New "
            Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <BoxView WidthRequest="100"
                             HeightRequest="100"
                             Color="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't get it what is the bug exactly

Comment: **1)** Are you saying that with an ItemsLayout Span of 3, if the collectionview has only 1 or 2 items, they do not show? If you add a third item, then it displays as expected? **2)** Add to question the xaml of `ItemTemplate` of this CollectionView.

Comment: 1) when item count minus from 3 to 2, all of them disappeared. Then back from 2 to 3, still not show. Then add from 3 to 4, all 4 items shows. 2) Added.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve 1) when item count minus from 3 to 2, all of them disappeared. Then back from 2 to 3, still not show. Then add from 3 to 4, all 4 items shows. 2) Added. Still suggest trying of the project directly.

Comment: Lets make sure the layouts know to fill the entire width: `<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"> ... <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"`. If that doesn't fix it, create issue at gihub maui issues, with link to repo.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve don't fix. I'll create a issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, I'll create a github issue.

Comment: Add to answer link to that github issue. And in github issue, add link back to this question. Thx.

Comment: lease use the comment feature instead, it doesn't look like and answer.